# Apply multiple agg functions on groupby index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the following wikipedia **scraper**:

```
import wikipedia as wp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Wikipedia __scraper__

wiki_page = 'Climate_of_Italy'
html = wp.page(wiki_page).html().replace(u'\u2212', '-')

def dataframe_cleaning(table_number: int):
    global html
    df = pd.read_html(html, encoding='utf-8')[table_number]
    df.drop(np.arange(5, len(df.index)), inplace=True)
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    df.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    find = '\((.*?)\)'
    for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
        if i>0:
            df[column] = (df[column]
                          .str.findall(find)
                          .map(lambda x: np.round((float(x[0])-32)* (5/9), 2)))
    return df

potenza_df = dataframe_cleaning(3)
milan_df = dataframe_cleaning(4)
florence_df = dataframe_cleaning(6)

italy_df = pd.concat((potenza_df, milan_df, florence_df))
```

Produces the following DataFrame:

[image]

As you may see I have concatenated the DataFrames, which result in a number of repeating lines. Using the `groupby` I want to filter all of these to be in a single DataFrame and using `.agg` method I want to ensure that there would application of `min`, `max`, `mean`. The issue that I am facing is inability to apply `.agg` method on row by row. I know it is a very simple question, but I've been looking through documentation and sadly cannot figure it out.

Thank you for your help in advance.

P.S. sorry if it is a repeated question post, but I was unable to find similar solution.

EDIT:

Added desired output (NOTE: was done on excel)

[image]

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: It would be a single DataFrame with first 5 [0:4] rows. With aggregated min, mean and max. The issue is that I want to apply 3 functions on the groupby.

Comment: You want to aggregate `min`, `mean`, `max` for all columns or row-wise?

Comment: Row, that's the issue I'm facing, I know how to do column wise, but row wise don't have an idea.

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 1:].min()`. Try this.

Comment: okay maybe an example: `italy_df = italy_df.groupby('Month').agg({italy_df.iloc[0]: np.min(), italy_df.iloc[1:4]: np.mean(), italy_df.iloc[4]: np.max()})`

Comment: Your command does not make sense at all. Cant you just post a sample output in exact same way you've posted input.

Comment: Added desired output @mayank-porwal

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ not scrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick update, I was able to achieve my desired goal, however I was not able to find a good resolution to it.

```
concat_df = pd.concat((potenza_df, milan_df, florence_df))

italy_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, index in enumerate(list(set(concat_df['Month']))):
    if i == 0:
        temp_df = concat_df[concat_df['Month'] == index]
        temp_df = temp_df.groupby('Month').agg(np.max)
    if i in range(1, 4):
        temp_df = concat_df[concat_df['Month'] == index]
        temp_df = temp_df.groupby('Month').agg(np.mean)
    if i == 4:
        temp_df = concat_df[concat_df['Month'] == index]
        temp_df = temp_df.groupby('Month').agg(np.min)
    italy_df = italy_df.append(temp_df)

italy_df = italy_df.apply(lambda x: np.round(x, 2))
italy_df
```

The following code achieves the desired result, however, it is highly dependent on the user's manual configuration:
[image]